# Category filter in list page magento2

Tags: magento2, filter, product-list

I am trying to filter products by category as below in the screenshot.

[image]

Once the category selected from the drop down the products belongs to that category should populate in the products section.

I need to populate child categories in dropdown once the parent is selected in first dropdown.

can we have this filter in list page?

Please anyone suggest me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get parent categories

```
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }
    public function getParentCategoryCollection()
    { 
      return   $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',0); 

     }
```

get child categories

```
    public function getChildCategoryCollection()
    { 
      $parentId = 1;
      return   $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$parentId); 

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add category filter(of Layred Navigation) on selection of category dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: not cleared with your answer

Comment: Just Populate drop with category options.Just fetch id with the jquery and
Add id of category behind URL.
localhost://men/tops-men/jackets-men.html?color=49

Thanks

Comment: Is above helped to you?

Comment: the second dropdown is depends on first dropdown selection. like first dropdown is main category, next is child category dropdowns

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144276)

Comment: @AasimGoriya, have you got my requirement?