# Load custom block in category list page magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, category-listing

I am trying to add custom template file in category list page.

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Magento_Catalog::product/myCustomFile.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

This is loading the template in list page.

But i need to load it from my custom module.

I used below code to implement it.

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_index.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_Module::product/myCustomFile.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

This is not loading my template in category list page. After using layout update also.

Can anyone help me on this please

Comment: Can you try to add it at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` ?

Comment: @amitshree, yes i need to add custom block in category page. yes tried it, that didn't work

Comment: This should work. Check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/181719/9169

Comment: @amitshree, yes now it worked, thanks, the content of that phtml is like below, can we implement it there, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256230/category-filter-in-list-page-magento2

Comment: Yes you can do that with some customisation. You need to call current category and sub-categories and render them as per your need.

Comment: In which part you want to add?

Comment: @amitshree, yes i need that logic how next dropdown is depends on first selection.

Comment: @RohanHapani, I need to move that block before the product list

Comment: If you want to show it somewhere else on the page, you need to use `move` node. This node sets the declared block or container element as a child of another element in the specified order.

Comment: @amitshree, yes i moved it to column top now, but i need the logic for that dependent selections

Comment: I do not have code for that. You can get sub-categories based on your current category selection and update you second dropdown using ajax call. See here how you can get sub-categories from your current category https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/magento-2-get-subcategories-of-specific-parent-category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create **catalog_category_view.xml** in your layout folder

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Addify_ProductSold::css/sales_style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_Module::product/myCustomFile.phtml" before="-" />

        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: how to move this block outside the content, like before footer

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>  
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Vendor_ModuleName::product/myCustomFile.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thanks